# How to record a call using Android kernel?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Recording Incoming and Outgoing Calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688444/android-recording-incoming-and-outgoing-calls)

I have searched a lot about it and I am aware of the fact that Google does not provide any API for recording a call and its not supported much. But I still see a lot of call-recorder apps in the android market. I have read somewhere that they use kernel for those apps. 
  I am also trying to create an app for recording a call(not on Microphone ofcourse). So can any one please tell me if it is possible or not? And if possible, then what are the steps to download and install the android kernel source code and how will we implement the changes in it for our particular app?

Comment: [Possible Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6688444/940096)

Comment: THis is a rather wide question? You ask if it can be done, then how to download/install kernel source thrown in the mix and finally when all that's over, how to implement the "changes" in the app? I suggest you find an idea first (you got one), and then try to find if you can do it. Then, if you can't find anything, come here and ask about it (your first question) to see if someone can help you. Then, if you got that worked out, start again: try if you can get the kernel. If you really can't, ask a new question, explain what happened, etc.You might've found what you are looking for on the way