# How can I check if somebody answers my call in Android

Tags: android

I can call some to with this code:

```
private void makePhoneCall(String number) {


    try {
         Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
         intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));``
         startActivity(intent);
         } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
         }
```

but I want to play something when somebody open to call.
how can I do ?

Comment: what? the question isn't clear,
to check if someone answered your call, see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684866/how-to-detect-when-phone-is-answered-or-rejected

Comment: Actually i want to call somebody and when he answer to calling, programme start to play tape recording. how can i do it programmatically

Comment: Ok, I see, so when your call is answered by someone, you want to record the session/call? see the answer on this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688444/android-recording-incoming-and-outgoing-calls

Comment: Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250455/detect-if-an-outgoing-call-has-been-answered) first.