# How to record phone calls in Appcelerator?

Tags: appcelerator, audio-recording, phone-call

I am trying to create an application that can record phone conversation, it can record incoming and outcoming call

I use Appcelerator to implement this app

I have read document in Appcelerator but can not find class/module/function or something like that can support record phone conversation

- Can i implement this app use Appcelerator/Titanium or must use native code ?
- Who have any suggestion for this question ?

Answer (score 0):

This requirement is not possible to be implemented with Appcelerator SDK along. You need to write modules (native code) for it and plugin into Appcelerator code.

Comment: Old, but this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688444/android-recording-incoming-and-outgoing-calls